# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 in recursive method with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to implement a recursive function to split an image into multiple small images for a puzzle game.

edit : Here is how ShapeObject's class init method looks (currently only supporting circles)
        //init method of ShapeObject

```
//shape currently has only a property named radius (it's a circle)
- (id)initWithShape:(Shape*)shape rotation:(float)rotation position:(CGPoint)position
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _position=position;
        _shape=shape;
        _rotation=MAX(0, MIN(rotation, 360));
        _color=nil;
        _shapePath=CGPathCreateMutable();


        CGPathAddArc(_shapePath, NULL, _position.x, _position.y, _shape.radius, 2*M_PI, 0, YES);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(_shapePath);
    }
    return self;
}

// in the processing class


-(void)recursiveTest:(ShapeObject*)shapeObject{
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeObject.shapePath), contextRect)) {
        return;
    }
    for (ShapeObject *obj in shapeObjects) {
        if (ccpFuzzyEqual(obj.position, shapeObject.position, 5)) {
            //break;
            return; //just return
        }
    }
    [shapeObjects addObject:shapeObjects]; //in front of method calls
    [self recursiveTest:[[ShapeObject alloc]initWithShape:shapeObject.shape rotation:0 position:findPoint(shapeObject.position, 300, shapeObject.shape.radius*2)]];
    [self recursiveTest:[[ShapeObject alloc]initWithShape:shapeObject.shape rotation:0 position:findPoint(shapeObject.position, 240, shapeObject.shape.radius*2)]];
    [self recursiveTest:[[ShapeObject alloc]initWithShape:shapeObject.shape rotation:0 position:findPoint(shapeObject.position, 60, shapeObject.shape.radius*2)]];
    [self recursiveTest:[[ShapeObject alloc]initWithShape:shapeObject.shape rotation:0 position:findPoint(shapeObject.position, 120, shapeObject.shape.radius*2)]];
    [shapeObjects addObject:shapeObjects];

}
```

The stack trace: 
[image]

After my logic it should work like this: check if it out of bounds & if it's already added in array. If not then call neighbors until all shape objects are in the array and whole picture is traversed.

I do all this in a background thread but as soon as i start the function i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2.

After a look around i found out that code 2 is something related with pointers.

Apparently the problem occurs where i create the path internally, but i don't get why it should, because there is no pointer there, just a simple CreateMutablePath, make the actual path from shape ,position and rotation, and close the path. That's it.

Also, its not a memory leak, i'm testing on my mac in simulator and i have enough memory free for all the possible objects. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I would definitely like to see the definition of `ShapeObject`. How is `path` stored there?

Comment: Just so we're clear here: `there is no pointer there, just a simple CreateMutablePath` - `CGPathRef` and other such Core Foundation objects are also pointers. Eg. `CGPathRef` is defined as `typedef const struct CGPath *CGPathRef;`

Comment: @Sulthan well they're all properties

Comment: add the definition of the 3rd method in stack: `updatePoints...`, also looks like a possible infinite recursion - how many stack frames are there?

Comment: @Mar0ux update points has CGPathAddArc and CGPathCloseSubpath in it , i copied the calls in the init to make it more readable

Comment: @Mar0ux it seems something happens at CGPathAddArc call, but i have no idea what

Comment: @skytz `_shapePath` is certainly valid. Two possibilities: `position` is a bad pointer or there's a infinite recursion - your recursion end code is not hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear from the stack trace that your recursion is too deep for the stack. Even though there is a lot of RAM available the stack is limited. The maximum stack size is a little unclear but I think it may be no more than 1MB.

Comment: I only see 38 frames listed... that could typically fit in the stack... I think that is a red herring... or at least could be... can't see enough

Comment: there are actually about 1000 frames...but there was a problem with the code itself too (first the add object should be in front of the next level calls, and then instead of the break;return;... just return). But yes..the stack isn't big enough for a recursive method of this type, i need to do something linear . Any ideas?

Comment: You need to find a way to limit the recursion, maybe your recursion ending criteria is not stopping soon enough.